# Windows Forms user controls on localizable forms cause display issues in Designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a simple user control (just an example): it is 40x100, but resizable. It has two buttons, one anchored at the top, one anchored at the bottom.

It put this control on a form and stretch it to 40x400. This works fine.

But as soon as I switch the form to Localizable = True and change the language to translate any strings, the Designer shows the user control
as if it was 40x100 for both the default an the translated language, i.e. the bottom button is not anchored.

Or better: the bottom button is *displayed* as if it *was* not anchored. The control occupies the correct amount of space (40x400), though (see selection highlight). And it displays fine during runtime, this is just a Designer issue.

[A picture showing the issue.](http://imgur.com/57b24QT)

Did I miss something here? Is this how it is supposed to work?

Im on VS2010 at the moment, tried the old VS2005 but it's the same there.

Thanks...

Comment: Every localization language have own resource file `yourForm.en.resx`. Through these files you can set different options for controls(.Text, .Location, .Top, .Left and so on). I think when you turn Localizable = true, designer generated resources for new languages but all options was reset

Comment: The strange thing is, the user control itself is _not_ resetted (its height), but only the controls _inside_ the user control. And only while displayed in Designer, not at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could easily repro this problem by anchoring the second button to the bottom.  The Anchor property has a few oddish failure modes, layout isn't always recalculated when it should be.  You found one such case.  I think the underlying issue is that the Size property is a localizable property as well and the designer fails to fire the required events when it starts a new localization set.  Something like that, nothing very trivial.

You'll need to punt this problem and *not* rely on the Anchor property to get the button positioned correctly.  That just takes a one-liner in your UserControl code, like:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
    button2.Top = this.ClientSize.Height - button2.Height;
    base.OnResize(e);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. For more complex controls it looks like it is enough to put all elements in one outer panel and do `OuterPanel.Width = ClientSize.Width` and `OuterPanel.Height = ClientSize.Height`. This makes everything display like intended, even if the elements inside the panel are anchored right or at bottom.